# Java URLEncode giving different results

Tags: java, character-encoding, url-encoding

I have this code stub:

```
System.out.println(param+"="+value);
param = URLEncoder.encode(param, "UTF-8");
value = URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(param+"="+value);
```

This gives this result in Eclipse:

```
p=指甲油
p=%E6%8C%87%E7%94%B2%E6%B2%B9
```

But when I run the same code from command line, I get the following output:

```
p=指甲油
p=%C3%8A%C3%A5%C3%A1%C3%81%C3%AE%E2%89%A4%C3%8A%E2%89%A4%CF%80
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: How is the `value` being passed into this code?

Comment: I can't reproduce your result. I just get the same output from command line as in Eclipse.

Comment: Could it be platform specific, because this happened to me on mac. But it doesnt happen on my linux box.

Comment: I am reading the value from a text file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your Mac was using Mac OS Roman encoding in the terminal. Those Chinese characters are incorrectly been interpreted using Mac OS Roman encoding instead of UTF-8 encoding before sending to Java.

As evidence, those Chinese characters exist in UTF-8 encoding of the following (hex) bytes:

- `指` = [0xE6 0x8C 0x87](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/6307/index.htm)
- `甲` = [0xE7 0x94 0xB2](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/7532/index.htm)
- `油` = [0xE6 0xB2 0xB9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/6cb9/index.htm)

Then check the [Mac OS Roman codepage layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman#Codepage_layout), those (hex) bytes represent the following characters:

- 0xE6 0x8C 0x87 = `Ê` `å` `á`
- 0xE7 0x94 0xB2 = `Á` `î` `≤`
- 0xE6 0xB2 0xB9 = `Ê` `≤` `π`

Now, put them together and URL-encode them using UTF-8:

```
System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode("ÊåáÁî≤Ê≤π", "UTF-8"));
```

Look what it prints?

> `%C3%8A%C3%A5%C3%A1%C3%81%C3%AE%E2%89%A4%C3%8A%E2%89%A4%CF%80`

To fix your problem, tell your Mac to use UTF-8 encoding in the terminal. Honestly, I can't answer that part off top of head as I don't do Mac. Your Eclipse encoding configuration is totally fine, but for the case that, you could configure it via *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding*.

---

**Update**: I missed a comment:

> *I am reading the value from a text file*

If those variables are originating from a text file instead of from commandline input — as I initially expected —, then you need to solve the problem differently. Apparently, you was using a `Reader` implementation for that which is using the runtime environment's default character encoding like so:

```
Reader reader = new FileReader("/file.txt");
// ...
```

You should instead be explicitly specifying the desired encoding while creating the reader. You can do that with the [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) constructor.

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/file.txt"), "UTF-8");
// ...
```

This will explicitly tell Java to read `/file.txt` using UTF-8 instead of runtime environment's default encoding as available by [`Charset#defaultCharset()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29).

```
System.out.println("This runtime environment uses as default charset " + Charset.defaultCharset());
```